# Проблема с STD:SET и итераторами

Tags: stl, итераторы, c++

Здравствуйте!

Что-то я затупил под конец дня...не получается реализовать набор данных (своего класса ) с использованием `**std:set**.` Вот мой тип данных, используемый для типа данных, находящихся в контейнере:

```
class employee
{
private:
    int id;
    string name;
    string adress;
public:
    employee(int id2, string name2, string adress2):id(id2), name(name2), adress(adress2) {}
    employee(){id = 0; name=adress="";}
    employee(int id2):id(id2){name=adress=""; id = id2;}
    int getID(){return id;};
    string getName(){return name;};

};
```

Ничего примечательного нет, не так ли? Также я перегрузил несколько операций, которые необходимо перегрузить для того, чтобы могли работать нектоторые контейнерные методы типа **std::set::find()** :

```
// Этот нужен для разнообразия...
ostream &operator<<(ostream &s,employee &emp)
    {
        s<<emp.getName()<<endl;
        return s;
    }

bool operator ==(employee a, employee b)
{
    return a.getID()==b.getID();
}

bool operator <(employee a, employee b)
{
    return a.getID()<b.getID();
}
```

Далее пытаюсь работать с самим контейнером через итераторы **std::set<class T>::iterator** :

```
    set<employee> emp;
    emp.insert(employee(123));
    emp.insert(employee(125));
    emp.insert(employee(124));
    set<employee>::iterator itr = emp.find(employee(125));
    cout<<*itr->getID()<<endl; // не работает
    cout<<*itr<<endl; // тоже не работает...
```

**Что не так, ребят? Подскажите пожалуйста...**

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Не компилируется?

Comment: Да, не компилируется. В обоих случаях выдает разные ошибки, но с одним смыслом, что, мол, идет недопустимое преобразование...

Comment: Советую проверить значение итератора, возвращаемого find, не указывает ли он на set::end, т.е. находит ли эта функция искомый элемент.

Answer (score 1):

cout<<*itr->getID()<<endl; // замен на iter->getId(), т.к. Ты пытаешься разыменовать строку, а не итератор
    cout<<*itr<<endl; // кажется тут выводится просто пустая строка (конкретно в примере)

Answer (score 0):

Не стал разбираться с кодом, попробуй изменить.

```
cout << *itr->getID() << endl; // не работает 
//на
cout << (*itr)->getID() << endl; // для работы с указателями
//или
cout << (*itr).getID() << endl; // а это как у вас с объектами
```

В зависимости, что у вас в контейнере: объекты или указатели на них.

Comment: Так тоже пробовал - не получилось. И вообще, вы привели полную лажу. Это, например, не применимо к указателям:

     (*itr).getID()

Comment: Не прочитав и не поняв моего примера ты минусуеш?
Я изменил в вашем примере тока

    cout << *itr->getID() << endl; // не работает
    на
    cout << (*itr).getID() << endl;

и у меня все компилируется!

Comment: Ну и человек, заминусовал правильный ответ и больше не заходит сюда так как он его и использует 100%, но написал что это лажа.

Comment: Из предложенных вариантов верен второй. Первый неверен. Надо писать 

     out << itr->getID() << endl;

Либо

     cout << (*itr).getID() << endl;

Comment: для работы с указателями


Я могу предложить несколько вариантов понимания этого комментария. Надо учиться писать без двусмысленности.

Comment: а предложение ниже кода не о чем не говорит?

Comment: не говорит

Comment: Кстати, надо писать "нИ о чем". Back to school